# Given atmospheric composition, density and scale height, planetary radius, and escape velocity, what is the lapse rate?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, atmosphere, weather, temperature

**My planet**

Mass = 0.602 M<sub>Earth</sub>

Radius = 0.870 R<sub>Earth</sub>

Density = 5.04 g/cm<sup>3</sup>

v<sub>esc</sub> = 9.3 km/s

Temperature = 272 K

**My atmosphere**

74.84% N<sub>2</sub>

22.04% O<sub>2</sub>

1.38% CH<sub>4</sub>

1.25% Ar

0.27% H<sub>2</sub>O

0.11% CO<sub>2</sub>

Molecular mass = 28.88

R<sub>specific</sub> = 287.90

Density at sea level = 1.18 kg/m<sup>3</sup>

Pressure at sea level = 0.91 atm

Scale height = 10013.78 m

Trying to find c<sub>p</sub> values, will edit them in if I find them.

This is all to determine if my atmosphere is realistically gonna be retained, and eventually to find the altitude of my tropopause.

Comment: 12.04% O2 and 1.38% CH4 is not stable over geological scale. You would need some active processes to keep these numbers that way, otherwise it'll bee CO2 and H2O relatively soon.

Comment: What processes might you suggest? I'm very new to this and I don't know where to start!

Comment: Most of the time such things are kept stable by biology, volcanic activity etc. Anything that can use energy to "under burn".

Comment: Excellent, I think I'll sequester my CO2 in plants, algae and bacteria, and have the bacteria produce a lot of methane and the plants produce a lot of O2. The rest I'll make up with volcanic activity--would you say that volcanoes can release a significant enough amount of CH4 to compensate for the difference?

Comment: I honestly don't know and it might be a start of a decent question, especially if you can make it a little bit more general. For me, it is believeable enough.

Comment: At 1.8 bar, 12% O2 and 1.4% methane in gas is really close to the lower flammability limit: 1.8% methane would explode if there was a source of ignition. About 16% O2 similar. Any local concentration near a source might reach that; perhaps you can work places like that into your story. “People who live in greenhouses shouldn’t smoke...”

Comment: Perhaps I’ve misunderstood, but that much water & pressure at 5C 278K) is a liquid. Liquids don’t have a lapse rate as such.

Comment: @BobJacobsen, of course! I'm such an idiot to have overlooked that. I was so focused on getting a powerful greenhouse gas into the atmosphere that I didn't even think about whether it would condense.

Comment: Replace the water with argon. It has about the same molecular weight.

Comment: First, if you want a realistic atmosphere, you are probably limited to: hydrogen, helium, methane, nitrogen, oxygen, argon, carbon dioxide, water vapor and ammonia. So pick from that list. Second, for your desired small mass, heavy atmosphere, I would go with CO$_2$, Ar, and O$_2$ in some combination. Third, you haven't edited this question in 20 hours, and it is not answerable since a water atmosphere is actually an ocean. I'm voting to close unless you are planning some edits.

Comment: Aa! thought I edited this.

Answer (score 4):

There are two lapse rates: dry and moist.

Dry is pretty simple. If we also assume equilibrium, then the lapse rate is just g/c_p in metric units.

If there’s a gas with high enough concentration that it condenses at some point, I.e. water forms clouds, then it’s much more complicated. The latent heat release results in several different possible outcomes, and you’ll have to work it through.

Sticking with “dry”, now you need to know Cp for your mix. Getting that exactly right is complicated, but we can approximate by looking at how far your mix of monatomic, diatomic and complex gases you have. Monatomic and complex gas additions move Cp in opposite directions, so will mostly cancel, and you’ve mostly got diatomic N2 and O2 just like air. So I suspect you’ll come out near air’s value of about 1.

Combine that with g and you’re done.

For more: https://hs.umt.edu/physics/documents/BOREALIS/Lapse%20Rate%20Terms%20and%20Formulas2012.pdf